# private member attribute is not working CI

Tags: codeigniter, class, attributes, private

Here is my model class

```
class Sessions_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $permission = array()
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function is_login()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) return TRUE;
        else return false;
    }
    public function login($username,$password)
    {
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            $user = $query->row();
            $this->set_authnication($user->id);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }

    public function set_authnication($user_id)
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $query = $this->db->where('id',$user_id)->get('users');
        $user = $query->row();
        $auth_data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'logged_in' => 1,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'username'=> $user->username,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'role' => $this->initRole($user_id),
            'lastVisitDate'=> now()
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($auth_data);
    }
    public function initRole($id)
    {
        $role_perm = array();
        $role = $this->db->where('id',$id)->get('roles')->row();        
        return $role_perm= array(
            $role->description => $this->getPerm($role->id)
        );

    }
    public function getPerm($id)
    {       
        $perms = $this->db->where('role_id',$id)->get('permissions')->result();
        foreach ($perms as $perm) {
            $this->permissions[$perm->permission] = true;
        }
        return $this->permissions;  
    }
    public function hasPermTo()
    {
        // $this->getPerm('1');
        // return (isset($permissions[$perm]))? 'true' : 'false';
        // print_r($this->session->userdata('role'));
        print_r($this->permissions);
    }

}
```

when i loggin username and password is set and call set_authnication($user_id).When this login method completed i've got Role with permissions.i set my private attribute with associate permission ..all things seem ok so far
My prob when user who is authnicated come i try to validate that this user has permission to the that class ,so i call function 
  $this->sessions_model->hasPermTo();
but this time my private attribute is empty array() .. it have nth ... 
i dont' what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

Your private variable is `permission` but you're settings `permissions` (note the S at the end).